# Clarification on usage of sum statement with subtraction

Tags: sas

In the dataset i have 3 variables id, type and value. I would like to calculate the score status named heart according to the type and value. 
the initial value for heart is 8.

There is error on the else if statement;

```
data score;
    input id type $ value;
    retain heart 8;  /*8 is initial value of heart*/
    if type = "add" then heart+value;
    else if type = "minus" then heart-value;
    else heart=heart;
    datalines;
1001 add 10
1002 minus 5
1003 add 2
1004 add 5
1005 minus 6
;
run;
```

Comment: More than likely your error is not on the `else`, but before the `else`, given the actual errant syntax is `heart-value`.  In the future please paste the relevant bits of log around the error to make it simpler to give you assistance.  (At least one line from the log before the line in error, the line in error, and then all the code down to the error message itself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum statment has the syntax, `variable+expression`. The plus sign is required. The hyphen `-` in your `else if` statement will not form a sum statement; instead, you must use: `else if type = "minus" then heart+-value;`.

Comment: hi @DWai. I lack of computer science background. What is the difference between +- and heart = heart - value? And what is this addition and subtraction style called?

Comment: Your questions are already covered by the answer.  The **sum statement** is what it is called.  The syntax is `variable+expression`.  So in your subtraction example the variable is `heart` and the expression is `-value`.  In the addition example the expression is just `value`.